# tinyMCE ssl/https files not loaded

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, tinymce

Tiny MCE config:

```
script_url: '/_js/tinyMCE/tiny_mce.js', // Location of TinyMCE script
```

When tinyMce editor is loaded on page it request few files (lang, plugins).
Everything is perfect when there is no https. Problem starts when https is on. Request paths are wrong and I cant find out how to fix this.

No SSL (example):

```
http://{domain}/_js/tinyMCE/langs/en.js?=201304041141
```

With SSL:

```
https://{domain}//langs/en.js?=201304041141
```

Any ideas how to fix that?
One application has few domains so giving absolute urls is not the solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was not SSL/NoSSL problem. This was dev/prod problem.
On production server .js are compiled to one file and cached.

Problem - cached file is in other directory than TinyMce additional files.

I don't delete my question, because maybe someday someone will be blocked by such stupid thing for a whole day like we did.